# Need assistance in understanding javascript order of precedence

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue understanding how the following statement is working.

```js
// setup
var n = 3;
var J = 3;
var g = 0;
var p = 41;
var m = false;
var O = 22;
var z = 15;
var I = [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,21,19,20,22,18,20,19,21,7,7,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,7,7,29,27,28,30,26,28,27,29,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,,,22]

// statement
n += J || (g = p, m = p < O ? g - 3 : g + 2, I[m] < z | I[m + O - p] || I[p += p - O]) ? 1 : 0;
```

At the end of the statement `n=4` but I don't understand how or why. I would expect:

```js
n += 3 || 1 // n = 6
```

This is someone else's code I'm trying to understand. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not really a helpful comment, but what the hell - no one should have to maintain this :(.

Comment: Frankly: ohh gaawwwwd! Yes, there *is* an answer, but no, nobody should have to try to find it in the first place, since code like this should simply not be written, unless you're trying to obfuscate  your code on purpose.

Comment: Show how you got to `1`, first, in as many steps as makes sense, so we can see where you misunderstood how to simplify a statement like this.

Comment: @deceze or you're playing "deep JS golf" where the entire point is to look at insanity like this to see if you understand JS parsing rules well enough to reach the same conclusion as a JS engine? =)

Comment: See [JavaScript Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple.

**J || (g = p, m = p < O ? g - 3 : g + 2, I[m] < z | I[m + O - p] || I[p += p - O])** ? 1 : 0

This above equals `(J || anything) ? 1 : 0`. Since J=3, it's like `(3 || anything) ? 1 : 0`.

`n += 3 || anything ? 1 : 0` -> `n += 1`

Comment: It's more readable to use a code block instead of bold highlighting.

Comment: I'm actually highlighting only a part of the statement, but that's fine, I can change it

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify your expression a little.

```js
n += X || Y ? 1 : 0
```

where

`X = J`

`Y = (g = p, m = p < O ? g - 3 : g + 2, I[m] < z | I[m + O - p] || I[p += p - O])`

Here we can see that we are evaluating `X || Y` and, on the basis of this, the ternary operator `?` returns a value of either `1` or `0`.

Since `X || Y` evaluates to `true`, we get `n += 1` impliying that `n = 4`.